# creating a map in which values will be of list type

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

Please advise i want to create a map in java as shown below as you can see  that    key is there but values of map is of further of list type  that is payername key can have list of values that is pn , pnb , gft , thy  so please advise how can we create such Map in java

```
   key                        values 
   payerName                  pn , pnb , gft , thy
   fixedRate                  re , et, try ,htre
```

please advise how to achieve this in java

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: In Java - keys and values can be of any type for Map so it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put ("payerName", Arrays.asList("pn", "pnb", "gft", "thy"));
map.put ("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("re", "et", "try", "htre"));
```

Answer (score 1):

[ListMultimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) from Google is nice, as well. It functions like a `Map<K, List<V>>` but without the overhead of having to initialize empty lists every time you add a key. That is, rather than writing:

```
if (!map.hasKey(key)) {
    map.put(new ArrayList<V>());
}
map.get(key).add(value);
```

you write

```
map.put(key, value);
```